How do I improve the performance of my api call?
Below I am making use of Admin - Get Activity Events rest api.
But I get the following error:

Error getting Power BI activity events: Failed to get Power BI activity events. Status code: 429. Response: {"message":"You have exceeded the amount of requests allowed in the current time frame and further requests will fail. Retry in 1584 seconds."}
Error: Failed to get Power BI activity events. Status code: 429. Response: {"message":"You have exceeded the amount of requests allowed in the current time frame and further requests will fail. Retry in 1584 seconds."}

It's only data for one day. Can I optimize my code any further or is this it? It's a question of the API's limit and the volume of my data. (The below was just a test.)
def get_power_bi_activity_events(access_token, startDateTime=None, endDateTime=None, continuationToken=None):
    events = []
    base_url = f"https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/admin/activityevents?startDateTime='{startDateTime}'&endDateTime='{endDateTime}'"
    headers = {
        "Authorization": f"Bearer {access_token}",
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }
    
    params = {}
    if startDateTime:
        params['startDateTime'] = startDateTime
    if endDateTime:
        params['endDateTime'] = endDateTime
    if continuationToken:
        params['continuationToken'] = continuationToken

    try:

        
        while True: #Chnage this back to true
            #print(f"Making request with params: {params}")
            response = requests.get(base_url, headers=headers)
            #print(response.json())
            
            if response.status_code == 200:
                response_data = response.json()
                events.extend(response_data.get('value', []))
                #print(f"Retrieved {len(response_data.get('value', []))} events.")
                
                continuationToken = response_data.get('continuationToken')
                if not continuationToken:
                    break
                params['continuationToken'] = continuationToken
            else:
                print(f"Failed request params: {params}")
                raise Exception(f"Failed to get Power BI activity events. Status code: {response.status_code}. Response: {response.text}")

        
        return events
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error getting Power BI activity events: {e}")
        raise



try:
    # Example usage
    start_date = '2024-05-24T00:00:00.000Z'
    end_date = '2024-05-24T23:59:59.000Z'

    # Get the access token
    access_token = get_access_token(url, client_id, client_secret)

    #Fetch power BI activities
    events = get_power_bi_activity_events(access_token, start_date, end_date)
    #print(f"Total events retrieved: {len(events.json())}")

I tried the above and expected the pull to be completed with no errors

HTTP 429 is unambiguous. In fact the API has embellished it with more detailed information. What is the "current time frame"?

Implement a caching mechanism to store API responses. For subsequent requests, first check if the data for the requested date is available in the cache. If it is, retrieve the data from the cache instead of calling the API.

I used
import diskcache as dc
Initialize cache
cache = dc.Cache('power_bi_cache')
cache_key = f"events_{startDateTime}_{endDateTime}"
cache[cache_key] = events
Still falls over
